# Ninject Binding for Lazy<T> where T's constructor has parameters

Tags: c#, constructor, ninject, lazy-loading

I have a lazy-loaded object that I would like to create an instance of via Ninject, but it doesn't work.

```
interface IFoo {
    string GetData();
}

class Foo : IFoo {
    private string _data;
    public Foo(string data) {
        _data = data;
    }
    public string GetData() {
        return _data;
    }
}

class MyModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IFoo>.To<Foo>().InTransientScope().WithConstructorArgument("data", "blah");
    }
}        

// ...

var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule());
Lazy<Foo> myFoo = kernel.Get<IFoo>();
Console.WriteLine(myFoo.GetData());

// Result:
// MissingMemberException: The lazily-initialized type does not have a public, parameterless constructor.
```

Its complaining that Foo doesn't have a parameterless constructor, which is true but why does it need one as I've provided NInject with the constructor parameter and it's value.

This works when I use `IFoo` instead of `Lazy<IFoo>`... so how do I specify that I want the Lazy-loaded object to also use the parameterised constructor?

Comment: This is line is not correct: `Lazy<Foo> myFoo = kernel.Get<IFoo>();`. have you meant `Lazy<Foo> myFoo = kernel.Get<Lazy<Foo>>();Console.WriteLine(myFoo.Value.GetData());`?

Comment: @nemesv: no, I think my code is correct... Ninject has in-built support for Lazy<>

Comment: No, as far as I know their is no built-in support. You need to manually register your lazy type as in the duplicate or use the https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory/wiki/Lazy as suggested one of the other answers in the duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

you cant get a `IFoo` and assign it to `Lazy<IFoo>` like you do in

```
Lazy<Foo> myFoo = kernel.Get<IFoo>();
```

get a `Lazy<IFoo>` instead

```
Lazy<Foo> myFoo = kernel.Get<Lazy<IFoo>>();
```

This requires Ninject.Extensions.Factory

Comment: How to achieve the same Lazy loading behaviour when we use constructor injection instead of Get?